# filter does not work properly in dplyr (Object not found)

Tags: r, dplyr

I have started working with dplyr library recently and experienced a very strange problem as I explain on the following example:

**Data:**

`df <- data.frame(Number = c(1,2), Letter = c('a','b'))`

`df = tbl_df(tst)`

**Problem:**

Running a select and filter like this:

```
df %>% select(Number) %>% filter(Letter == 'a')
```

gives me the error:

```
"Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) :    
Evaluation error: object 'Letter' not found."
```

While I can change the order of select and filter and it works OK:

```
df  %>% filter(Letter == 'a') %>% select(Number)
```

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 1 x 1

Number

 <dbl>

1    1
```

I could not find any place that explains if it is a general rule and there is some order for using **dplyr** key functions or there is another problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this line

```
df %>% select(Number) %>% filter(Letter == 'a')
```

The first call to `select` leaves you with a data table containing only one column (`Number`). Which is exactly why `filter` is complaining - you threw the `Letter` column away.

In the second call, you filter on `Letter` first, **then** throw the column away.

So, `filter` is working exactly as it should. There is no "general rule" for this beyond either "do things in a sensible order" or "garbage in garbage out"

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. I had forgotten that it is a chain process and the further functions apply to the most recent results.